# mLab is shutdown, ObjectRocket start from 46$ a month, does it mean heroku no longer has free mongodb addon option?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab, mongodb-atlas

I like to offer people easy to launch open source project, but it seems heroku no longer provides free mongodb options, am I right?

Comment: MongoDB Atlas has a free tier.

Comment: mlab free tier is available directly from their website (without Heroku integration).  You will have to make your user to copy the URL and put it manually as an env variable.